# How can I use strftime function with question mark in Java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, date, strftime

I am planning to add 'Date' objects into the SQLite database. However, I am getting an error about the insertion being null.
The error is this

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL]  A NOT NULL constraint failed (NOT NULL constraint failed: dates.Tarih)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:825)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.execute(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:53)
```

This is my code. I suspect from the question marks. Because when I remove them and place them with `'now'`. It actually works. But, the following code throws the above error.

Insert method

```
public static void insert(Date date, Date date2)  {
       try{
           System.out.println(" date:"+date.toString());

           String query = "insert into dates(Tarih,Tarih2) values(strftime('%d-%m-%Y',?), strftime('%d-%m-%Y',?))";
           pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
           pst.setObject(1,date);
           pst.setObject(2,date2);

           pst.execute();

       }catch (SQLException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }


    }
```

Comment: Whatever your date objects are being converted to by `setObject` is in a format not understood by `strftime()`. See https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values for what it can work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have defined the column `Tarih` as `NOT NULL` and your code is trying to insert a `null` value in the table.

The reason that you get `null` from `strftime()` is because you don't pass a valid date for SQLite.
For SQLite valid dates/datetimes are either strings in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, or integer unix epoch times or floating point numbers representing julian days.

What you pass are Date objects and this is your mistake.

One way to solve the problem is to extract from each of the `Date` objects an integer representing unix epoch time and pass that to `strftime()`:

```
public static void insert(Date date, Date date2)  {
    try{
        long d = date.toInstant().toEpochMilli() / 1000; 
        long d2 = date2.toInstant().toEpochMilli() / 1000;

        String query = "insert into dates(Tarih,Tarih2) values(strftime('%d-%m-%Y', ?, 'unixepoch'), strftime('%d-%m-%Y', ?, 'unixepoch'))";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setLong(1, d);
        pst.setLong(2, d2);
        pst.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to convert it to Timestamp. I just want to insert it as dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: @Demir I know that. strfime() does not format unless you pass a valid date. date and date1 are Java's Date objects and not valid dates for SQLite. My code gets the timestamps from these Date objects and uses them inside strftime() with the modifier 'uniepoch' to instruct the function that these numbers are timestamps that need to be formatted.

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea. It works perfectly.